# Switch default bootstrap styles with different ones

Tags: theming

I have this [site](http://theme.zephirus.pt/robot_runs) that's using a subtheme of Drupal Boostrap theme. The contents are mainly made with views. I want to change the look of the table on the link with the style of the condensed table on this [boostrap template](http://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524954-kadmin-free-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/live-demo)

How can I achieve this? Do I define the css to use in views? Should I change the style.css in my subtheme to override the default css with the new one? Should I copy the css files of the new theme?

I'm really lost on how to apply the styles to the subtheme. Can someone guide me on how to do it or if there's some kind of tutorial for this particular case: Bootstrap Template do Drupal Theme.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could approach this issue with any of the solutions you just mentioned. If it's just a table you are theming, I don't know that I would necessarily go through the trouble of creating an entirely new theme or sub-theme for just that component. Can you use the bootstrap styles and simply integrate them into your site with different class names?

Comment: Hi Maria, thanks for your answer. I already have a bootstrap subtheme so I will try to change the table style.